# Icon doesn't change with class change in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to customize a Bootstrap (v3.3.5) Collapse Panel by displaying an icon in the corner and changing it : Open/close icon snippet.
Here's a working version in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/omZRcD2UPM).

In my case I try to change the icon from other sources.
The problem is that the code is working well on Google Chrome, but the icons/images are not displayed on Firefox and InternetExplorer.

Is this a bug in bootstrap, or it could be easily fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap. The classes are being changed properly by your jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `content` css property with pseudo-elements, so instead of:

```
.icon-close {
    content: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesignoffice5/256/navigate-down.png");
}
```

Try

```
.icon-close::before {
    content: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesignoffice5/256/navigate-down.png");
}
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/V3sW1gkfp0)**